# How we can Import Objective-C Constants as Swift Types?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants, swift3

I want to declare constant in `Swift 3`. For example if we have following constant in Objective-C :

```
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight;
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass;
```

Comment: are you want to declare global constant  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add New Swift file : **Constant.swift**

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit

let HK_EXTERN_Height : NSString = HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight
let HK_EXTERN_BodyMass : NSString = HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass
```

Use in **ViewController.swift**

```
print(HK_EXTERN_Height)
print(HK_EXTERN_BodyMass)
```

Hope this help you....

Comment: Thanx :) for helping me

Comment: @MohsinQureshi anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding constants into a separate file is also possible in Swift.

For using constants, it is even smarter, if you use `structs`, because huge number of constants can be messy:

```
import HealthKit

struct Constants {

    struct Health {

        struct Quantities {
            let height : NSString = HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight
            let bodyMass : NSString = HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass
            static let minWeight: Double = 30.0
        }  
        ...          
    } 
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
print(Constants.Health.Quantities.minWeight)
```

or

```
let healthNumbers = Constants.Health.Quantities
print(healthNumbers.minWeight)
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe in the Swift language you can  declare using let key word.